# Magento 1.9.2.1 test emails sending, but order emails not

Tags: php, email, cron

I'm using magento to set up a webstore. I'm using Aschroder SMTP Pro, and wiring it through Zoho to send emails.

(The zoho email is myname@projectname.com, and I have it set up as the email for all the different fields in the settings customer support, sales, etc)

I did a test transaction using paypal sandbox, and that was succesful. Then I used the magento "ship" and "invoice" options to update the order. Here's where it gets wonky. *The first time I did it (this morning) it worked. The second time I did it (about 8 hours after) it no longer sent the email.*

I don't remember changing any settings so I am at a loss. I've been reading around and I have checked my cron jobs and done a test email.

The test email I got, and the cron job was working from my cPanel.

**The cronjob looks like this:**

`php -f /home/projectname/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null`

and it is set to run every 5 minutes.

I've heard there can be some issues with the cron jobs from reading up, but mine should be working. Not only that but I manually went to the cron.php in my browser and nothing changed)

Answer (score 1):

This is because order emails as of Magento 1.9+ need to have a working cronjob to send the order emails. You can test this by manually running yourdomain.com/cron.php in a browser.

You can find instructions on setting up a cronjob for Magento at http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-setup-a-magento-cronjob/

You can also find more information on troubleshooting your cron at:
http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/troubleshooting-a-magento-cronjob/